# Jquery Loop for Path Builder

Tags: javascript, jquery

String -> Delimited Array -> Loop Generated Check Boxes -> String Builder
String = "Folder Tier1\Folder Tier2\Folder Tier3\Folder Tier4\Folder Tier5\Folder Tier6\"
(Missing) Delimited by "\" to create a checkbox for each tier
Currently I can only produce 1 check box
(Finished) For each selected checkbox it builds a new string.
With a working delimiter loop checking off boxes 3, 4, and 5 would produce
"\Folder Tier3\Folder Tier4\Folder Tier5\"

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wseqpn9y/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSave').click(function() {
        addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
    });
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
   var container = $('#cblist');
   var inputs = container.find('input');
   var id = inputs.length+1;

   $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name, checked:true }).appendTo(container);
   $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
   $('<br>').appendTo(container);
}

$("#clickme").click(function(e){
  var SelectedBoxArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map( function() {
    return this.value;
 }).get().join("\\");
    alert(SelectedBoxArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Folder Tier1\Folder Tier2\Folder Tier3\Folder Tier4\Folder Tier5\Folder Tier6\" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" value="Generate Checkboxes" id="btnSave" />
<div id="cblist">
</div>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Alert Selected" />
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Further expanded on the question and added my current progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $input = $('#txtName');

  $('#btnSave').click(function() {
    //get the value, split on slash, and create a checkbox for each value
    $input.val().split('\\').forEach(addCheckbox);
  });

  $("#clickme").click(function(e) {
    var SelectedBoxArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join("\\");
    alert(SelectedBoxArray);
  });
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
  //handle for if the string starts with or ends with a slash, or contains two slashes
  if (!name.trim()) return;

  var $container = $('#cblist');
  var $inputs = $container.find('input');
  var id = $inputs.length + 1;

  //build the elements
  $container.append(
    '<input type="checkbox" id="cb' + id + '" value="' + name + '" checked>' +
    '<label for="cb' + id + '">' + name + '</label><br>'
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Folder Tier1\Folder Tier2\Folder Tier3\Folder Tier4\Folder Tier5\Folder Tier6\" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" value="Generate Checkboxes" id="btnSave" />
<div id="cblist">
</div>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Alert Selected" />
```

Comment: The handle for \'s prepended, appended, and/or double instances is very intuitive. At first I started to think JQuery .trim() did more than white-space since I didn't see a .replace('\',''); anywhere in the script. Now I see that it has to do with an exit on a blank checkbox name, that is some very clean design intent. Also this is exactly what I envisioned 100% resolved.

Comment: The 5 minute window to edit my previous comment expired, forgot to add that this is highly appreciated and thank you Taplar.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/sthkzLpa/4/

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var SelectedBoxArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map( function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join("/");

  console.log(SelectedBoxArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="chunk" class="chunk-style" value="Folder Tier1" checked/>Folder Tier1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chunk" class="chunk-style" value="Folder Tier2" checked/>Folder Tier2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chunk" class="chunk-style" value="Folder Tier3" />Folder Tier3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chunk" class="chunk-style" value="Folder Tier4" />Folder Tier4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chunk" class="chunk-style" value="Folder Tier5" />Folder Tier5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chunk" class="chunk-style" value="Folder Tier6" checked/>Folder Tier6<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chunk" class="chunk-style" value="Folder Tier7" checked/>Folder Tier7<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chunk" class="chunk-style" value="Folder Tier8" checked/>Folder Tier8<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chunk" class="chunk-style" value="Folder Tier9" checked/>Folder Tier9<br>
```

Comment: Those check boxes are to be dynamically generated from delimiting a string. Sorry I should of been more clear, I removed the input html from my post to avoid further confusion.